# Path Analyzer showing wrong name for error page

Tags: path-analyzer

My team has recently started looking at the path analyzer to start getting an idea of traffic flows and we have realized that the error page isn't coming up as the error page. Rather it has been showing up as "Favicon". I have noticed it other names (second image shows it labeled "blogs"), but this is the one that is seen the most. I checked our set up for the error page and it is set up per Sitecore standards. I also went through the error page item, and it is using our regular page template similar to 90% of the pages across our sites. Our sitecore instance is multisite and this issue affects all of our sites.

The favicon icon is set up through partials/page design so it is the same for all pages. This is the media item; "[...] enterprise-imagery/fav-icons/tjcfavicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />"

I am not sure where else to look for why Path Analyzer won't show the item name and any ideas / help is appreciated.

Thank you

[image: Error Page Path Analyzer Item - named favicon]

[image: Error Page Path Analyzer Item - named blog]